# Do I really need to learn xml for android development?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a Python programmer and I want to learn android app development. My million dollar question is, **do I really need to learn xml?** Can't I just use the design tab in android studio and drag n drop elements to make the design?

Comment: [Is learning xml necessary for android app development?](https://www.quora.com/Is-learning-xml-necessary-for-android-app-development)

Comment: Well You just need a basic understanding of XML, its a really easything to do anyways, and then with a basic understaning of xml you can develop fairly easily,

Comment: drag n drop is useless in complex designs and also you need to set attributes in you widgets directly to xml so you need to familiarize the xml layouts, so Yes you need to learn xml layouting.

Comment: The editor and design tab in Android Studio is getting better and better in helping you avoid the need to edit the xml file manually, and the ease with which you can switch between the design and tet tab in your xml, makes it so easy to absorb the knowledge without having to sit yourself down and read about it. Start developing and it will happen organically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well well it should be noted that whether any technology is used in certain IDE it would be good to have some background knowledge or at least know what is it for..
Overall is not hard to learn XML at a functional level.

**What is it?**

A Xtensinve Markup Language which basically work with tags, it was created for be self-descriptive.

```
<deliveryTag>
    <to>Michelle Obama</to>
    <from>Barack Obama</from>
    <note>Happy Birthday!</note>
    <type>First Class</type>
    <package>Regular Size Box</package>
</deliveryTag>
```

**What is it for?**

Designed for carry data, and have it well-organized of course.
People really loved how it simplifies the data sharing, transport and availability eventually it became one of the standards cross-platform.

**Finally..**

- XML was designed to carry data -> it focus on what data is.
- HTML was designed to display data -> it focus on how data looks
- Both of above are NOT programming languages but languages for structuration.
- You will have more control over your project even if you drag and drop, at some point you will note that Android Studio demands to fluently use XML in many parts of the software development cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just use drag and drop editor, all attributes can change there, but when u face with an issue, you can't find your answers in Here because all of android developers work with xml.

It's too easy to learn, don't afraid of it.

Comment: As a former web dev I know CSS and xml is similar but the point is, I don't like coding designs instead, I like coding logic and draw designs.

Comment: you can do it and just need to know so little xml side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the design tab for constructing the application UI, But for complex design, it's not advisable.